# Array Java que devuelva solo el texto que hay a partir de la última coma de la frase

Tags: java, array

Nuestro array es el siguiente

```
String[] frasesPosibles={"El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz Cardillo y Kiwi","Adêle La cigüeña es una inútil","El aliento de mi gato huele a comida de gato","Si mi calculadora tuviese un historial de operaciones, sería aún más vergonzoso que mi historial de búsqueda del navegador","Si me levanto 10 minutos más temprano de lo normal, lo trato como si fuesen 2 horas extra, y acabo llegando tarde.","Los alienígenas invadieron la luna el 20 de Julio de 1969","Tiene que meter el miedo en el cuerpo el leer ‘no tocar’ en braile", "Las personas guapas con personalidades horribles son la versión en ser humano de los Clickbait","Si los alienígenas vienen a la tierra, tendremos que explicarles por qué hay cientos de películas donde los matamos y echamos de nuestro planeta."};
```

1.Crea un método llamado despuesDeLaComa, que reciba un String por argumentos, y haga lo siguiente:

--Si no tiene ninguna coma, lo devuelva tal cual

--Si tiene alguna coma, que devuelva solo el texto que hay a partir de la última coma de la frase. Por ejemplo, en la frase:

**”Si me levanto 10 minutos más temprano de lo normal, lo trato como si fuesen 2 horas extra, y acabo llegando tarde.”**
debería devolver: **“y acabo llegando tarde.”**

--Asegúrate de que lo devuelve sin ningún espacio al principio ni al final. En este ejemplo, no debería haber ningún espacio antes de la “y” en el array devuelto.

Mi pregunta es como puedo solucionar eso

este es mi código

```
public static String fraseComa(String arr[]) {
    String ret="";
    int coma=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != null) {
            coma =arr[i].indexOf(",");
            ret += arr[i].substring(29, arr[i].length());
        }
    }return ret;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza las librerías de String, te comparto un ejemplo que puede procesar lo que requieres:

```
package stacoverflow;

public class StacOverFlow {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] frasesPosibles={"El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz Cardillo y Kiwi",
            "Adêle La cigüeña es una inútil",
            "El aliento de mi gato huele a comida de gato",
            "Si mi calculadora tuviese un historial de operaciones, sería aún más vergonzoso que mi historial de búsqueda del navegador",
            "Si me levanto 10 minutos más temprano de lo normal, lo trato como si fuesen 2 horas extra, y acabo llegando tarde.",
            "Los alienígenas invadieron la luna el 20 de Julio de 1969",
            "Tiene que meter el miedo en el cuerpo el leer ‘no tocar’ en braile", 
            "Las personas guapas con personalidades horribles son la versión en ser humano de los Clickbait",
            "Si los alienígenas vienen a la tierra, tendremos que explicarles por qué hay cientos de películas donde los matamos y echamos de nuestro planeta."};
        for( String frases : frasesPosibles )
        {
            System.out.println(StacOverFlow.fraseComa(frases));
        }
       
    }
    



    public static String fraseComa(String frase) {

        return frase.contains(",") ?  frase.substring(frase.lastIndexOf(",")+1).trim() : frase;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Israel Ramos

Answer (score 0):

Optarías por pasar un String como parámetro y no como array..lo primero seria obtener la cantidad de (",") que aparecen en la frase para así obtener el indice.. lo siguiente es usar el método **split()** para fraccionar la frase en partes pasando  como separador (",")..por ultimo haces una condicional donde usas el método **contains()** el cual valida si la frase contiene(",") si es así imprimes la parte del arreglo que obtuviste con split en la posición del indice que obtuviste con el for,el cual vendría a ser la ultima "," en la frase de esa manera el método solo imprime esa parte de no ser así imprime la frase completa

```
public class Operacion{

    public static String  fraseComa(String frase){
        String aux;
        int cont=0;
         for(int i=0;i<frase.length();i++){
           if(String.valueOf(frase.charAt(i)).equals(",")){
                 cont++;
           }
         }  
        String[]fraccionDeFrase=frase.split(",");

        if(frase.contains(",")){
            aux=fraccionDeFrase[cont];
        }else{
           aux=frase;
        }return aux;

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

String frase ="Si me levanto 10 minutos más temprano de lo normal, lo trato como si fuesen 2 horas extra, y acabo llegando tarde.";
    
System.out.println(fraseComa(frase));

}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el enunciado de tu problema indica que tu método `despuesDeLaComa` debe recibir como parametro **un String**, entonces puedes recorrer letra por letra comenzando desde el final de la frase hasta encontrar una coma, en cada comparación incrementamos un contador para saber cuantas letras se ha comparado. Al final solo nos queda extraer la subcadena y si queremos que no tenga espacio al principio y al final usamos el método `trim()`.

```
public static String despuesDeLaComa(String frase){        
        int cont=0;        
        
        for(int i=frase.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            //recorrer cada letra hasta encontrar la primera ',' comenzando del final
            if(frase.charAt(i)==','){
                break;
            }
            cont++;
        }  
        String subCadena=frase.substring(frase.length() - cont);
        
        //devolvemos la subcadena sin espacios al princio y al final
        return subCadena.trim();
    }
```